# How to change report orientation on MS Acces?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form with combo boxes rounding down selection of records from a table and a button which generates report based on selected record via VBA command, all of it works fine, except that generated reports are horizontal by default, is there any way to change default orientation or some simple command that would rotate the report in MS Access? In essence I want my report to be like in picture no. 2

Report generating code that I'm using:

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "DATA", acViewPreview

DoCmd.SelectObject acQuery, "DATA"

RunCommand acCmdNewObjectAutoReport

DoCmd.Close acQuery, "DATA"
```

What I am [getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qft5L.png)

What I [want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppiYI.png)

Comment: I would suggest you to design report first then use query as data source of report.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Design View -> Page Settings -> Page Layout -> Vertical

See the screenshot below:
[image]

Now change the size of your report by making it smaller in width.
That's it!